# хочу посмотреть код элемента а он закрывается

Tags: html, selenium, https, firefox, браузер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хочу развернуть data-test-id="select-menu-wrapper"

при нажатии сворачиваются дни и элемент пропадает как это исправить?

Comment: Попробуй в дев тулсе нажать `:hov`, и там потыкать галочки.

Comment: @OliverPatterson не помогает :'(

Comment: Значит придется ручками класс вешать, печально.. погляди кому какой класс дается при клике, подозреваю `isOpen`.

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select/option[@value='значение']").click()
```

Попробуйте этот вариант

**Import**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
```

**Code**

```
age = 20

driver.get('https://account.mail.ru/signup?from=main&rf=auth.mail.ru')
time.sleep(2)

dayInput = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='base-0-2-102 first-0-2-107']/div[1]/div[1]/div[@class='Select__control css-0' and 1]/div[@class='Select__value-container css-0' and 1]")
dayInput.click()

time.sleep(1)

days = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div/div[2]/span[@class='base-0-2-63 control-0-2-69 auto-0-2-85' and 1]")
for day in days:
    if day.text == str(age):
        day.click()
        break
        
time.sleep(500)
```

Comment: в чем и проблема не могу копировать xpath

Comment: можете дать ссылку ?

Comment: ссылку на сайт?

Comment: да именно, я посмотрю что там можно сделать

Comment: https://account.mail.ru/signup?from=main&rf=auth.mail.ru

Comment: сейчас попробуйте

Comment: мне нужно именно через firefox

Comment: это не имеет значения, измените на firefox